# check the user_id in the array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have logged as approver_id ='897'. Request table have `request_id,approver_id`

```
request_id  approver_id
 005         897
 006         [897,91] 
 007         91
```

I want to fetch the records where  `$approver_id is 897`In a laravel query 
I have to get the row where the approver_id is 897 so expected 005 and 006

```
 $user=".."; //Query stuff
 $user=$user->where('request.flag','=','1')
 ->orwhereIN('asset_request.approver_id',array($approver_id))->get();
```

I didn't get any rows how to check the approver_idis in the table row

Comment: you have store your data in wrong way

Comment: Is any other format  to store ?

Comment: I agree with @rkj, however, using `wrap` should work: `orwhereIN('asset_request.approver_id', wrap($approver_id))`

Comment: I've never seen `orwhereIN`. Is this standard Laravel?

Comment: caught Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\wrap() error

Comment: refered in https://hotexamples.com/examples/illuminate.database.query/Builder/orWhereIn/php-builder-orwherein-method-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

i don't recommend to store information like this but if you need then store it as a json. And then you can fetch it like this

```
$requests = Request::whereJsonContains('approver_id',[$approver_id])->get();
```

Here `Request` is a model class for `requests` table

details https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereJsonContains

Comment: If I stored in  897,91 istead of [897,91] Is it easy to check in query

Comment: [897,91] is better than 897,91. because first one is a json. try `whereJsonContains`

Comment: I'm  using 5.3 so not supported

Comment: changed to 897,91 as per ur suggestion

Comment: then don't use `897,91` too better create a separate row

Comment: I can't create 2 rows for single request